# SASS nesting(for readability), is it a bad practice?

Tags: css, angular, sass

A more experienced co-worker told me to nest all my SCSS, so it would reflect its look in HTML, claiming it would do wonders for readability.

I am really concerned that this is unnecessary and could potentially slow down the application(angular) dramatically.

in the reformatted document, the selectors are going 5 levels in, while in the original it never passed the 3.

What is ts the best practice to use nesting is SASS? should it be used only when it would its necessary for specificity purposes? or it can be a better way for formatting my document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try not to directly nest them in a way that's identical to the nesting of the HTML as you're quite right, you would have an unnecessary amount of selectors in your CSS.

There is a great book on https://smacss.com/ that teaches you to split your code into modules instead. I would recommend sectioning your HTML to blocks/modules and nesting relevant selectors rather than all selectors.

Rule of thumb: the more selectors you include, the stronger priority it holds when styling.

Note: I would recommend looking into stylus as I think this improves readability over SCSS.

Comment: What about performance? would unnecessary selectors cause a slow down in the application?

Comment: Yes it would as the file size would be larger. You generally have to compromise with readability and performance. Although, it is hardly noticeable with the performance gain/loss. I would make selectors short and precise and only include more selectors for specificity, rather than for readability. - Ben frain has a post on this (https://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/#h-H1_11)

Comment: Sass / SCSS nesting might perhaps make the code better understandeble but there is the tradeoff that too much nesting will create complex selectors in the resulting CSS. Search for complex selectors and performance, preferably in the last year or so as browsers are getting more clever. Having said that, you might not perceive a difference, and having a solid Sass/SCSS structure might help you in understanding and debugging your code.